# What is the difference between SpeechSynthesis and chrome.tts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, text-to-speech

The chrome.tts for extensions (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tts) and SpeechSynthesis (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis) APIs seems to be able to do the same things. I don't really see any differences besides a few differences in the available functions, but they can still do the same thing. Are there any differences I should be aware of?

Edit: I need to use this specifically for a chrome extension, I'm aware chrome.tts is only for chrome extensions/apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome’s TTS is propriety to Chrome and is pre-standard, whereas the SpeechSynthesis API is in the process of being standardised (I.e. non-proprietary and is available in other, non-Chrome based browsers).

Comment: I added that I need it for a chrome extension, so the fact it's only for Chrome doesn't really matter (should have added that before). Are there any other differences that you're aware of?

Comment: Other browsers like Edge and Firefox support most of Chrome’s extension APIs, but by using the (almost) standard API you might get better support. Additionally proprietary APIs tend to be discontinued and removed once the standard version becomes well-accepted. I’d go with the standard version.